# writing to cloud firestore via cloud functions not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write data into cloud firestore from cloud functions, and I am not getting it to work.  Here is my code in cloud functions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var express = require('express');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const app = express();

let db = admin.firestore();

app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {


  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;


  //creating document.  Here is where it isn't working

  let docRef = db.collection('UsersMain').doc('firstdoc');

    let data = {
    Email: 'a@gmail.com',
    UserName: 'Matt'
  };

  let setDoc = docRef.set(data);

console.log(db);
  res.send('Login Complete');
});



const api1 = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = {api1};
```

and here are my firestore permissions:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Ideally, a new document called 'firstdoc' would be created and it would have the Email and UserName data in it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that pops to mind looking at your code is that you're not waiting for `docRef.set(data)` to complete before sending a result back to the caller. This means that Cloud Functions may kill your environment, before the write to Firestore is completely.

To ensure the write is completed, you should only write a result to the response once the write to the database is completed. Something like:

```
docRef.set(data).then(() => {
  res.send('Login Complete');
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen!  I'm now getting a permission denied error.  I'm looking into it right now and will almost certainly select your answer when I figure it out

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen.  I am still getting "Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."  The firestore permissions are the same as listed above.  Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: You didn't say anything about getting a permission denied in your question, did you? Anyway: Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK to access Firestore, which means they  bypass the security rules of the database. If this error is indeed coming from your Cloud Function, it's not due to the security rules.

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen.  My bad, thanks again!  I will accept your answer and make a new question.  I am completely lost with regard to this.